# right click menu options not working in qtp

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

i am trying to automate a .net based windows application using UFT

here i am facing a problem using the swftoolbar options,i am using UFT 12.01 with .NET ad in loaded.
This is the code i used to add a media item which gives rise to a  dialogue box in our application

```
SwfWindow(...).SwfToolbar(....).Press "Add New Media"
```

when we use “ .press” or “.select” operator for any option present in the right click menu, UFT hangs after performing the operation and i have to manually close the dialogue box every time it appears  in order to make UFT run again.the dialogue box is being identified correctly, but execution stops at the above mentioned line

also tried the following ways but can’t find a way to solve it

**Using select operator:**

```
SwfWindow(...).SwfToolbar(....).select "Add New Media"
```

**Getting the option in a variable and selecting it:**

```
Var1= SwfWindow(...).SwfToolbar(....).GetItem(0)
SwfWindow(...).SwfToolbar(....).Press Var1
```

also tried using descriptive programming but it didn’t worked out.

i have tried using the shortcuts for the right click menu options and it works perfect.

i can't rely on shortcuts for every option as the application has a lot of right-click options

if anyone found the answer please post it, it would be a great help for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got solved the problem with UFT 12.02... download the UFT 12.02 patch and install.. Its working fine now

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Now feel free to accept your own answer so the question gets out of the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

You should try emulate mouse if normal right click is not working. With web based apps it works pretty fine:

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
obj.rightClick
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

You can try to add coordinates if it won't work.